# How upload a file and send text-plane information in Java Web Application with POST

Tags: java, forms, jsp, uploading

I can upload file in Java Web Application, but, if I want to send information and upload file, the system upload file and consider the information as null!

My code:

1. Servlet:

   ```
       protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
       throws ServletException, IOException {
       if (request.getParameter("information") == null)
           System.out.println("information is null");
       Helper helper = new Helper();
       String url = "C:\\Users\\.....<private url>";
       DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
       factory.setSizeThreshold(1024);
       factory.setRepository(new File(url));
       ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
       try{
           List<FileItem> partes = upload.parseRequest(request);
           for(FileItem items: partes){
               File file = new File(url,items.getName());
               items.write(file);
           request.getRequestDispatcher("view/upfile/upfile.jsp").forward(request, response);
           return;
           }
       }catch(Exception e){
               request.getSession().setAttribute("error", e.toString() + ": " + url);
               request.getRequestDispatcher("view/excepciones/message.jsp").forward(request, response);
           return;
       }
   ```

   }

File JSP:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Subir el archivo</h1>
    <form action = "<%= request.getContextPath() %>/UpFilesController" method="post" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
        <input type = "file" name = "file"/>
        <input type = "text" name = "information"/>
        <input type = "submit" name = "action4" value = "Subir Archivo"/>
    </form>

</body>
```

**Out of GlassFish Server:
information is null**

Comment: This question was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet